# Java Read/Write, Rename File having issue

Tags: java

I was using my code to do a replace line feature. It was working initially but suddenly my new file became blank and the code did not bring me back to the `AdminMenu()`, as well as the file not being renamed. There is also another issue where if I use `"\r\n"` there will be a blank line on top of my file which I am trying to remove. I tried using `\n` after `totalChips`, but it doesn't seem to work. I could use some advice on this.

output

```
<Blank File>
```

expected output

```
Line1|password|500
Line2|password|600
//ModifiedLine can be either line based on UserName
```

codes are below

```
 public static void AddChips() {
      File oldFileName = new File("players.dat");
      File tmpFileName = new File("newplayers.dat");

      BufferedReader br = null;
      BufferedWriter bw = null;

      ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFileName));
         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tmpFileName));
         String line;
         Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please Enter Username");
         String UserN = read.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Please Enter Chips to Add");
         String UserCadd = read.nextLine();

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] details = line.split("\\|");
                String Username = details[0];
                String Password = details[1];
                String Chips = details[2];
                int totalChips = (Integer.parseInt(UserCadd)+ Integer.parseInt(Chips));
            if (Username.equals(UserN))
               line = Username + "|" + Password + "|" + totalChips;
               bw.write("\r\n"+line);
         }

            bw.close();
            br.close();
            oldFileName.delete();
            tmpFileName.renameTo(oldFileName);
            AdminMenu();


      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
          return;
      } finally {
         try {
            if(br != null)
               br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         try {
            if(bw != null)
               bw.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

}
```

new Error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at testcode.AddChips(testcode.java:53)
at testcode.main(testcode.java:11)
```

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` in **each** `catch` block.  You're suppressing all exceptions.

Comment: after i added that i got Arrayoutofbounds when the array is the same....

Comment: Post (add to your question) the entire exception and full trace back.

Comment: it was working fine previously

Comment: and line # **53** in your `testcode.java` file is ...?

Comment: password. it is hashed

Comment: Add `if (details.length < 3) System.out.println( Arrays.toString(details) );` right after you do the `split()`. I have a strong suspicion that something is wrong with your your `players` file, possibly an empty line at the end. If this is indeed the case it explains why it stopped working with the same code.

Comment: my details becomes blank nothing inside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74985/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-ken).